# cascading saving on EF 4.1 not getting saved

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

I am trying to save cascading in EF 4.1 code first.

```
[Table("User")]
public class User
  {
    [Key]
    public Int64 UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual UserRole UserRole { get; set; }

}

[Table("UserRole")]
public class UserRole
{
    [Key,Column(Order = 0)]
    public int RoleID { get; set; }
    [Key,Column(Order = 1)]
    public Int64 UserId { get; set; }


}
```

when I am trying to save the user by populating the userrole inside it. it is giving error.

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_User_UserRole". The conflict occurred in database "x", table
>   "dbo.User", column 'UserId'. The statement has been terminated.

```
using (Database database = new Database())
{                
      database.User.Add(user);
      database.SaveChanges();  //it is giving error here.
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure the shared primary key mapping. Otherwise EF can not order the insert statements properly. In your case a `User` record has to be inserted first and then insert the `UserRole` with the generated primary key of `User`.

```
[Table("User")]
public class User
  {
    [Key]
    public Int64 UserId { get; set; }

    public virtual UserRole UserRole { get; set; }
}

[Table("UserRole")]
public class UserRole
{
    [Key,Column(Order = 0)]
    public int RoleID { get; set; }

    [Key,Column(Order = 1)]
    public Int64 UserId { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

In your `OnModelCreating` method

```
modelBuilder.Entity<UserRole>().HasRequired(r => r.User)
   .WithOptional(u => u.UserRole);
```

Then

```
var user = new User { UserRole = new UserRole() };

using (Database database = new Database())
{                
      database.User.Add(user);
      database.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried reproduce error as follow, however it succeeded

```
    using (var db = new MyContext())
    {
        var user = new User { UserRole = new UserRole { RoleID = 1, UserId = 1 } };
        db.Users.Add(user);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

can you elaborate your code more detail to get the same error?